# Is there really a difference between http://example.com and www.example.com?

Tags: javascript, css, http, web

I seem to have stuck in this weird issue.  If I open my website by giving the address as `http://example.com`, it opens up fine.  But if I enter the address as `www.example.com` or `http://www.example.com`, then the site opens as if the browser is JS disabled (and without any CSS formatting).

I tried in IE, Firefox and Chrome.  The issue occurs consistently.

Is there really any difference between `http://example.com` and `www.example.com`?

If yes, then is there any way to give a consistent experience to the user irrespective of how he landed on the site?  Maybe, by redirecting him to the `http` site even if he used just `www`.

Comment: Are you sure that `http://www.mysite.com` works but `www.mysite.com` doesn't? Those two should be absolutely identical.

Comment: You will need to be a little more specific if you'd like to know about redirection.

You can redirect using only JS, but there are nicer ways if you're using say IIS or PHP or something like that.

eg. We're using IIS7 here with a URL rewrite to redirect people to `www`.

Comment: @Nathan: I don't use IIS or PHP.  My site is hosted by inmotion.  They provide support to both of these but I might not be able to immediately learn and do it that way.  Can you tell me the JS way so that I can do a quick fix (atleast temporarily) ?

Comment: @John: I too thought so but it turns out to be incorrect.  The answer from Kolink explains the reason.

Comment: @John: My bad.  You are right.  Those 2 show the same result.  I will edit the question.

Comment: @Ramnath Without being too tricky, this should be fine `if (window.location.hostname == "www.mysite.com") { window.location.hostname = "mysite.com"; }`. Run that on each page you want to redirect. The down-side is that they need to have Javascript enabled, so your best bet is still to contact the hosting provider and ask for their assistance.

Comment: @Nathan: Thanks, I contacted my hosting provider and they have now setup the redirect. My site works fine now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. `www.example.com` is a subdomain of `example.com`. *Typically* they are the same site, but not necessarily. Some servers will only accept one or the other. Others (like mine) will redirect `www.domain.tld` to `domain.tld` for easier cookie handling. Others still (very few) host completely different websites.

Answer (score 2):

Try redirecting www.mysite.com to mysite.com. You can achieve this by modifying your .htaccess file. This is also good for search engine optimization since as far as search engines are concerned, the two are separate entities. By redirecting, you are telling the search engines that both are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Although most out-of-the-box vhost configurations will treat the two the same, you can specifically set it to behave as 2 different sites.